# Passing javascript variable to next php page

Tags: javascript, php

So I have this php file where form is located.

```
<head>
<script src="js/create_competition.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id='create-competition' action='create_competition_action.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

    <div id="main">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add" class="bt" />
    </div>

    <input type='submit' id='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</body>
```

And when you press the add button a field is created on the page. When you press it again, another field is created and so on. And when a field is created a variable in create_competition.js gets bigger by 1.

Now when lets say there is 3 field created and after that submit button is pressed I want to pass that variable (which is 3 at the moment) to create_competition_action.php so I could use the knowledge of how many fields was created there. But I have no idea how I can do that.

I tried using this in create_competition.js

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
      alert(nrFields); // to see if works
      window.location.href = "create_competition_action.php?var=" + nrFields;
    })
```

Alert worked, after pressing submit I got an alert of how many fields was created but window.location.href did not.
But other then that I have not found any good solutions on how to do it.

Comment: Put a hidden field into the form, put the number into its `value` via your script … and then let the form submit normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo error in your function. You are alerting **nrField** and appending **nrFields** with **s** at end.

But if you need count for iteration or something simmilar, you can use arrays:

```
 <input type="text" name="values[]" />
```

and then in PHP

```
 foreach($_POST["values"] as $value) ...
```

Comment: Thanks with the typo and the array method worked perfectly so thanks for that too.

Answer (score 0):

How about when you click the "add" button it creates the field with this a name like this :

```
<input type='text' name='data[]'/>
```

set this same name (`data[]`) to every inputs.

Then, server side :

```
<?php
$nb_fields = count($_POST['data']);
```

If you want to be sure you can iterate on `$_POST['data']` as it's an array, and remove empty or invalid values...